# SSH - Driving me insane

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am using the latest ubuntu 22.04.03 on a headless system. SSH continues to add these lines to the top of the config file each and every reboot, therefore locking me out.

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
PubkeyAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
PidFile /run/sshd.pid
```

I have purged, edited, reinsalled, disabled, and I cannot for the life of me get this to stop.

Please help me. Pretty please?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in the *default* Ubuntu configuration that would cause this behavior - does the server perhaps have a cron job that is modifying the file?

Comment: check your system's syslog messages

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add: i) your Ubuntu version and ii) what config file you are referring to.

Answer (score 3):

So after months of craziness, I figured it out. The suggestion above to look at my cron jobs led me to my Jumpcloud managment agent. As this was a new Nix build only months ago, I forgot to enable the SSH settings in the agent. My sanity is saved. Thanks for the suggestions!!